# Swiss File #4 Alternatives

Tags: tools

I want to buy a "Swiss File #4".

I visited some local stores but noone knew what that was.

I found this nice set of files. Can someone read what it says in the top?
Is some of these file equivalent to "Swiss File #4"?

If yes, i will buy this instead.

[image]

Comment: Another bumped question to hang around forever....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the US, the wording you are looking for is "Needle File Cut 4", I believe.

Amazon search: https://www.amazon.com/s?k=needle+file+cut+4&ref=nb_sb_noss_2

A Diamond file is not the same, having industrial diamond particles embedded into the surface, rather than teeth cut into the steel.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(tool)#Diamond_files

It is possible that the files in your photo would work well for your application, but they are **not** equivalent to a Swiss #4.

Comment: Thank you! I searched for Nicholson files but they are not labelled "Cut 4". Instead it says (4"-6"-8"-10"-12"). The 4" is equivalent to Cut 4? Sorry for this question, i am not a US resident.

Comment: No, that's not the same. The Double Prime means "Inches", so this will refer to the length of the file, most likely. N.B. The Swiss grading system goes from #00 (coarse) up to #6 (very fine), so anything larger than 6 is *not* a grade

Comment: What country are you based in, and why are you looking for a Swiss #4 *specifically*?